# Angularjs routing: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to trigger angularJS routing inside of a function in controller, but it throws back "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined". Can't really see where I missed $location injection, guess it's the reason.

```
var gameApp = angular.module('gameApp', ['ngRoute']);

gameApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $provide) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider

  // route for the home page
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'home.html',
    controller  : 'mainController'
  })

  // route for the game page
  .when('/game', {
    templateUrl : 'game.html',
    controller  : 'gameController'
  })

  // route for the game over page
  .when('/game-over', {
    templateUrl : 'game-over.html',
    controller  : 'mainController'
  })

  // default
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

And part of my game controller when I'm using router

```
gameApp.controller('gameController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){
    function gameLost($location){
        var check = false;
        console.log ('You lose! Your score is ')
        $location.path('/game-over');
```

}])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
function gameLost($location) {
        var check = false;
        console.log ('You lose! Your score is ')
        $location.path('/game-over');
}
```

Unless you invoke this function like this `gameLost($location)` (which I doubt) `$location` is going to end up as undefined in local function scope, overwriting `$location` service from parent closure scope.

So I think all you need to do is to remove `$location` paremeter from `gameLost` function definition:

```
function gameLost() {
        var check = false;
        $location.path('/game-over');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helped to get rid of error. Passing $location as function argument where the function is invoked does the same thing. Routing, however, doesn't happen. I would be grateful if you or anyone has any idea about it.

Comment: i got this "http://localhost:8000/#!/game-over"  why this -> '/#!/'  ??

Comment: @Benyamin If you are not using history mode (`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`) then the fallback is going to be hash mode `#` or `#!`. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location